# Editing the starting position of something in a VBO?

Tags: java, lwjgl

So currently I am working on learning and creating something small in LWJGL 2. I've almost got the hang of using VAOs and VBOs but I'm unsure about something. How do I edit the starting position of an object that I have stored in a VBO? I may have not explained it very well but I am curious as to how you would draw the object in a certain place when it's rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to only draw a part of the VBO? To do that you need to call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, offset, vertexcount)`, where offset is the first vertex you want to render and vertexcount the count of vertices to render.

Comment: I probably haven't explained it very well. I just want to render the whole VBO (Which now, only contains one triangle) I just want to know how to tell it where to be positioned on the screen when it does render.

Comment: +PandaCo Ok, thats a little more complicated... You will have to either specify the position on initializing, change the data using glBufferSubData or using programs... Do you already use programs? You need them for almost everything that is more complicated than drawing a colored square. If you look for a good resource for learning OpenGL in general, I learned almost everything on that site: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ .